# Node lite-server gzip file

Tags: node.js, angular, gzip, lite-server

I am using lite-server locally for angular2 dev. I compressed all my js into a min.js file with 1.7Mb which is working fine. Now I want to squeeze it to a gzip file with 280Kb which is much smaller. 
The bad part is that Chrome is downloading the file with content-type "octet-stream" instead of "application/javascript" and the Content-Encoding "gzip". 
Is there any simple way of making this work?

Comment: Look at what headers your server is sending. You can see these in the chrome inspector in the network panel under the resource in question.

Comment: as i said: it's sending the file as 'octet-stream' and thats my problem. Here's the headers:

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:295997
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Mon, 04 Jul 2016 09:58:44 GMT
ETag:W/"4843d-155a79e0518"
Last-Modified:Fri, 01 Jul 2016 17:59:59 GMT

Answer (score 2):

Not very familiar with `lite-server`, but since it seems to accept Express middleware you should be able to use the [`compression`](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) middleware:

```
// lite-server-config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  server : {
    middleware : { 1 : require('compression')() }
    ...
  }
};
```

That will take care of the compression for you, so you don't have to gzip the files manually. It will also set the correct headers.

Comment: thanks your answer oriented me to fix this problem with this answer: https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/tree/master/recipes/server.gzipped.assets